# What are my options for sending data from Windows app back to developer without using a webserver

Tags: c#, web-services, email

I am writing a simple WPF quiz application for a family member and he would like users of this application to have the option to send him their scores once they have completed the quiz. I was hoping to do this without the need to create some kind of webservice for the app to talk back to.

My initial idea was to email the results back, but that runs into problems. What if there is no SMTP client on the user's machine? I don't want to embed a password for a public smtp server into the application. I could do a `Process.Start("mailto:...")`, but that requires their machine to have a handler for mailto: and for them to click submit on the generated email.

Another idea I had was that the app could add a line into a Google docs spreadsheet, but that would mean a google docs password would need to be embedded in the app.

So my question is, without me writing a separate application running on a webserver for my WPF app to talk to, is there a good way of my app sending data back to me that doesn't require a password? I'm guessing there must be some kind of public webservice I could use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with a third party service that can do this for you, consider [Parse](https://www.parse.com/), or any other 'backend as a service' provider.

You should then be able to implement something else that reads the saved data from the service when required, without having to expose itself as an API.

Comment: +1 - was playing around with it.  Besides parse, there's similar cloud simple storage like S3 and Azure table storage.

Answer (score 1):

Create a google doc forms and when you need the user to submit their score, launch a web browser with the doc url. You can auto-populate the fields by query parameters( ... `&entry_0=Barney&entry_1=Google&` ... )

Comment: it works, although still requires them to click submit (and allows them to modify their score!). Still might be the easiest option though

Comment: To prevent manipulation of the score, you can add another field to the form populated with a hash of the score. That way you won't rely on what they had put in (and also you can test their honesty :))